# Loading js files asynchrously, onExecution event?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have two javascript files that I want to load asynchrously, a.js and b.js.

a.js must run before b.js.

I was hoping I might be able to trigger the execution of b.js with something like the following:

```
$.getScript("a.js")
    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        $.getScript("b.js")
})
```

The trouble is, if a.js is very large, even though it loads first, occasionally b.js will load and execute before a.js has finished executing, causing an error.

How can I get around this quandary?

Comment: the most obvious would be to use require.js, which was built for dependency loading.

Answer (score 0):

Not as pretty, but pretty sure this will do it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "a.js",
    dataType: "script",
    async: false
}).done(function(msg){
    // do something
});
$.getScript("b.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
    // do something
});
```